# VictoryChart not change date data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, victory-charts

I have a victory chart and two axis at the same, following this chart

https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/gallery/multiple-dependent-axes/

There is nothing much i can describe, but this chart now look like this
[image]

But problem is i can't change the date data, althought i change the date

```
<VictoryAxis
  crossAxis={true}
  tickCount={12}
  data={date}
  tickFormat={(x) => {
    console.log(x);
    return x.toLocaleString("vn-vn", {
      month: "short",
      day: "numeric"
    });
  }}
/>
```

And the date data

```
const date = [
  { x: new Date(2000, 3, 4) },
  { x: new Date(2003, 4, 17) },
  { x: new Date(2004, 1, 1) },
  { x: new Date(2005, 1, 1) },
  { x: new Date(2006, 1, 1) },
  { x: new Date(2007, 2, 1) },
  { x: new Date(2008, 1, 1) }
];
```

But it alway show `1 jan` , please help

This is live demo and data

https://codesandbox.io/s/chart2-11eut?file=/src/App.js:776-1010

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array:

```
const date = [
  new Date(2000, 3, 4),
  new Date(2003, 4, 17),
  new Date(2004, 1, 1),
  new Date(2005, 1, 1),
  new Date(2006, 1, 1),
  new Date(2007, 2, 1),
  new Date(2008, 1, 1)
];
```

Amend the JSX as follows:

```
  <VictoryAxis
  crossAxis={true}
  tickValues={date}
  tickCount={date.length}
  tickFormat={(x) => {
    return x.toLocaleString("vn-vn",
      {month: "short", day: "numeric"})
    }
  } 
/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but it not work, it still stuck at jan 1 at all value

Comment: you can try directly at codesandbox

Comment: Here is a full sample https://codesandbox.io/s/chart2-forked-5104p?file=/src/App.js